# Parse CSV inside actionURL repeated twice Liferay 7

Tags: csv, post, timeout, liferay, liferay-7

My problem is when I post a csv file in a form my process action is being executed but before finish the execution (need to check line by line and do some stuff) a new execution started.

I check Chrome console and seems to be that when it took more than 30 seconds the navigator reload itself and new action starts.

Any idea how can I increase timeout or other solution?

```
<aui:form name="importQuestions" action="<%=importQuestionsURL%>"  method="post" role="form">
    <aui:fieldset>
        <aui:field-wrapper label="editorquestions.importQuestions.csv" helpMessage="editorquestions.importQuestions.csv.help" >
                <aui:input inlineLabel="left" inlineField="true" name="fileName" label="" id="fileName" type="file" value="" >
                    <aui:validator name="acceptFiles">'csv'</aui:validator>
                </aui:input>
        </aui:field-wrapper>
    </aui:fieldset> 
    <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button type="submit" cssClass="btn btn-primary"></aui:button>
        <aui:button name="close" value="close"  type="button" onClick="<%=backToSearchQuestionURL%>"> </aui:button>
    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

Inside my logic is a loop... about 550 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `javascript.single.page.application.timeout` in your server's portal-ext.properties:

```
#
# Set the timeout in milliseconds before SPA navigation times out and falls
# back to standard navigation.
#
javascript.single.page.application.timeout=60000
```

But you should use this only as a workaround in your development environment.

For long running background-tasks you should consider Liferay's BackgroundTask framework. See:

https://web.liferay.com/de/web/daniel.kocsis/blog/-/blogs/background-task-a-k-a-the-secret-weapon-behind-the-new-asynchronous-staging